# How to match from a string of just Ones and Zeros certain sequences of these digits?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I tried this on regex but the quote

```js
 let stringdata = "01110010100111101000111";
let output= stringdata .match(/(10)1?|(01)+0?/g);
console.log(output);
```

currently output, the code above is like this , I have missing **single quotes**
[image]

**but I want the output like this** , did I miss something?

```
'01','','10','0101','','01','','','01010','','01','','',''
```

Comment: it would be helpfull and add clarity if you tell us what rule/pattern it should follow. I really don't get the pattern you want to address

Comment: Your desired results include empty strings, but your regex requires that any match has at least two characters.

Comment: Where do the empty strings come from? Are they supposed to represent the parts of the input that don't match the pattern? A regexp match can't return something that isn't in the input. You could use `re.exec()` in a loop, and when there's a gap in the indexes you can return an empty string.

Comment: The OP might have gotten confused by the pattern and or the expected result since `'01010'` (the 6th expected entry from right) is not even part of the `stringdata` value. Maybe the OP meant `'1010', '', '01', '', ''` for the last 5 entries?

Answer (score 0):

From my above comment ...

> *"The OP might have gotten confused by the pattern and or the expected result since `'01010'` (the 6th expected entry from right) is not even part of the `stringdata` value **[sic ... since it already has been consumed]**. Maybe the OP meant `'1010', '', '01', '', ''` for the last 5 entries? "*

In case the made assumption is correct the OP is looking for either of the following character sequences ...

- either the pattern `01` as sequence (non capturing) ... `(?:01)+` ...
- or the pattern `10`  as sequence (non capturing) ... `(?:10)+` ...
- or simply a single `1` ...
- or simply a single `0` ...

... which makes the regex look like this ... [`/(?:01)+|(?:10)+|1|0/g`](https://regex101.com/r/eqG6Xp/1).

Since either alternative will be [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)ed the OP needs to run an additional mapping task which replaces the single character values by an empty string in order to achieve/assure the expected (according to my assumption) result.

```js
const stringdata = '01110010100111101000111';

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/eqG6Xp/1]
const regXSequences = /(?:01)+|(?:10)+|1|0/g;

console.log(
  stringdata
    .match(regXSequences)
);
console.log(
  stringdata
    .match(regXSequences)
    .map(value => value.length >= 2 && value || '')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -3):

This is my answer

First problem : `let result = text.match(/(0101)|(01)|(10)*/g)`

Second problem : `let result = text.match(/^.{0,20}/g);`